# Remove duplicates values in array Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to know how to remove duplicates values from 2 arrays, combined into one main array.

This values must NOT be removed from the sheets or document, just in the array, thats why I didnt use clear() or clearContents() built in functions;

Ive also tried to modify the [removeDuplicates()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates) function from the GAS tutorials, but it throws me rows inside columns from A to Z, instead filtered rows...a total mess.

**Notes:**

Parameters from **getClients()** are from others functions, and works ok.

**newClients** list clients from the sheet 'Users' and **newUsers** list users from another sheet called 'Data'.

Boths sheets belongs to the same spreadsheet.

**newClients and newUsers**: both arrays only contains strings (usernames), and in both there are duplicated values.

So the goal is identified and remove those values, the original and the duplicate.

Should be easier I think, but Im new in JS, so everything Ive been tried, didnt worked.

Thanks

**The Code**

```
function getAllClientsFromData(body,project){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Active the Sheets
  var sheet= ss.getSheets()[1,3];

  // Access data in Sheet "Data"
  var rangeC = ss.getRangeByName("clients"); //A:2:C273  
  var rangeU = ss.getRangeByName("names"); //A5:A

  var clients = rangeC.getValues();
  var users   = rangeU.getValues();

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()-2;

  body += "<h2>Total of " + lastRow + " clients in " + project + "</h2>" 
  body += "<table style=" + STYLE.TABLE + ">";
  body += getClients(ss,clients,users,project);
  body += "</table>";

  return body;  

}

function getClients(ss,clients,users,project){

  var body = "";

  var newClients = [];

  for( var g = 0; g < clients.length; g++ ){

    var currentProject = clients[g][2];

    if( clients[g]!= "" ){

       newClients.push(clients[g][0]);

    } 

  } // end for

  var newUsers = []; 

  for( var u = 0; u < users.length; u++ ){

    if( users[u] != "" ){    

      newUsers.push(users[u][0]);

    }

  } // end for

  var allData = newUsers.concat(newClients);

  var uniqueData = allData.sort();

  body += "<tr><td style=" + STYLE.TD + ">" + uniqueData.join("</td><tr><td style=" + STYLE.TD + ">") + "</td></tr></tr>";

  return body;

}
```

**UPDATES!**

The answers works great filtering, but Im getting the same result as on my previous tries: displaying the filtered results. I need to remove them from the array. example:

```
var array = ['aa','bb','aa','ff','pp', 'pp'];
filtering code...
var array = ['bb','ff'];
```

I try to add splice() js method but the params I pass, does not working ok.

Comment: when you say "it didn't work", what was the actual output or error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The array you are working on is not a 2D array anymore since you extracted the fields before sorting... so you can use a very simple duplicate removal function as shown below with an example and some added `Logger.log` to see how it works.

```
function test(){
  var array = ['aa','bb','cc','aa','dd','cc']
  Logger.log(removeDups(array));
}

function removeDups(array) {
  var outArray = [];
  array.sort():
  outArray.push(array[0]);
  for(var n in array){
    Logger.log(outArray[outArray.length-1]+'  =  '+array[n]+' ?');
    if(outArray[outArray.length-1]!=array[n]){
      outArray.push(array[n]);
    }
  }
  return outArray;
}
```

in your code this would replace the line

```
var uniqueData = allData.sort();
```

that would become :

```
var uniqueData = removeDups(allData);
```

---

**EDIT :**

If letter case is an issue, you can modify this code to ignore it. You should change the condition **and** the sort function so that they both ignore the case in your names but preferably keep the original letter case.

This could be achieved with the code below :

```
function test(){
  var array = ['aa','bb','Cc','AA','dd','CC'];// an example with Upper and Lower case
  Logger.log(removeDups(array));
}

function removeDups(array) {
  var outArray = [];
  array.sort(lowerCase);
  function lowerCase(a,b){
    return a.toLowerCase()>b.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;// sort function that does not "see" letter case
  }
  outArray.push(array[0]);
  for(var n in array){
    Logger.log(outArray[outArray.length-1]+'  =  '+array[n]+' ?');
    if(outArray[outArray.length-1].toLowerCase()!=array[n].toLowerCase()){
      outArray.push(array[n]);
    }
  }
  return outArray;
}
```

Logger result :

[image]

---

### EDIT 2 :

Here is another version that keeps only unique values (I didn't understand correctly your request in the first version as it kept one element from the duplicates...)

I simply added an `else if` condition to remove the elements that were part of a group of duplicates.*(I kept the case insensitive version but you can remove it easily)*

```
function test(){
  var array = ['aa','dd','hh','aa','bb','Cc','cc','cc','bb','nn','bb','AA','dd','CC'];// an example with Upper and Lower case
  Logger.log('original array = '+array);
  Logger.log('unique result = '+removeDups2(array));
}


function removeDups2(array) {
  var uniqueArray = []
  array.sort(lowerCase);
  function lowerCase(a,b){
    return a.toLowerCase()>b.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;// sort function that does not "see" letter case
  }
  var temp = array[0];
  for(var n=1 ;n<array.length ; n++){
    Logger.log(temp+'  =  '+array[n]+' ?');
    if(temp.toLowerCase()!=array[n].toLowerCase()){
      uniqueArray.push(array[n]);
      temp = array[n];
    }else if(uniqueArray[uniqueArray.length-1]==temp){
      uniqueArray.pop();// remove it from result if one of the duplicate values
    }
  }
  return uniqueArray;
}
```

Logger result new code :

[image]

Comment: Only worked for me after applied `.toString()` at the end of `outArray[outArray.length-1]` and `array[n]` in the last if statement.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I had to make a change/addition (I know next to nothing about JS). I kept getting `function () {
        return this.filter(function (value, index, self) { return self.indexOf(value) === index; });
    } ?` so I changed `if (outArray[outArray.length - 1] != array[n])` to 
`if (outArray[outArray.length - 1] != array[n] && n != "unique")`.  I don't know enough to know what caused this issue or if my "fix" is suitable, so I wanted to run it by you.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are not doing anything to filter the duplicate values. 
This line will just sort the data and won't give you unique data.

```
var uniqueData = allData.sort();
```

You can do something like this on your merged array, after you 'installing' 2DArray lib: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library

```
var uniqueData = unique(allData);
```

Another option is to create a loop and check for duplicate values, but you should remember to transform all the values of the string to lowercase before you do these matches.

Answer (score 2):

I created this function and it worked.

```
function removeDups(data) {
  var newData = [];

  data.forEach(function(value) {
      if (newData.indexOf(value) == -1) {
        newData.push(value);
    }
  });
  return newData;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Considerate of you to leave a comment with the code confirming that it *does* work. Please make it a habit to document *in your code a) what it accomplishes* and *b) how*, if not blatantly obvious. Please revisit the examples in the last paragraph of the question for an idea why anyone would vote your answer *not useful*.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
function removeDups(array) {
  array.sort()
  var lastValue = !array[0]
  var outArray = array.filter(function(value) {
    if (value == lastValue)
      return false
    lastValue = value
    return true
  })
  return outArray
}
```

This also works correctly for empty arrays whereas some earlier solutions yield [null] in this special case.

Answer (score 0):

Serge insas you are the best man!

A thing I improve in your code, removeDups2, an error caused because the first element, even if its not duplicate, it does´t appears in the uniquearray. To solved this problem, just declarate for the first time =>

> uniqueArray = [array[0]]

So de code stay look like this, and work very well

```
function test(){
  var array = ['aa','dd','hh','aa','bb','Cc','cc','cc','bb','nn','bb','AA','dd','CC'];// an example with Upper and Lower case
  Logger.log('original array = '+array);
  Logger.log('unique result = '+removeDups2(array));
}


    function removeDups2(array) {
      var uniqueArray = **[array [0]]**
      array. Sort(lowercase);
      function lowerCase(a,b){
        return a.toLowerCase()>b.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;// sort function that does not "see" letter case
      }
      var temp = array[0];
      for(var n=1 ;n<array.length ; n++){
        Logger.log(temp+'  =  '+array[n]+' ?');
        if(temp.toLowerCase()!=array[n].toLowerCase()){
          uniqueArray.push(array[n]);
          temp = array[n];
        }else if(uniqueArray[uniqueArray.length-1]==temp){
          uniqueArray.pop();// remove it from result if one of the duplicate values
        }
      }
      return uniqueArray;
    }
```