# How do I Merge Column Values in Google Sheets with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I recognize that this question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735677/remove-duplicates-values-in-array-google-apps-script). I'm sad to say, I just don't know enough to follow that one.

I also recognize that it is very similar to the [Google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates#running-a-simple-example), but they are creating a new array, and I need to combine arrays.

**The problem**

I'm trying to create a permanent list from a volatile list. The permanent list will be updated daily. I need the script to look for duplicates on one sheet, and copy everything new to another sheet. I'm pretty sure that my problem lies mostly in my logic.

I've been bashing together all the similar answers I could find to help (commented out) and I just can't figure it out. More explanation below.

[Spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15DRZRQ2Hcd7MNnAsu_lnZ6n4kiHeXW_OMPP3squbTLE/edit?usp=sharing)

[Script here](https://script.google.com/a/fjuhsd.org/d/1rWxkZiZhOYZ8PziNp03VrwQXF8nJyWET1knpJdrhTL4uG181IgN3TtfD/edit?usp=drive_web)

**Code.gs**

```
    function updateRoster() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp
    .openById("15DRZRQ2Hcd7MNnAsu_lnZ6n4kiHeXW_OMPP3squbTLE");
  var data = ss
    .getSheetByName("Volatile Data")
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues();
  var saveData = ss
    .getSheetByName("All Data")
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var value = data[i][3];
    for (j in saveData) {
      var search = saveData[j][3]
      if(value == search) {
        Logger.log(data[i][3]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get this in the Log:

[16-03-24 06:35:44:914 PDT] 1.00000006E8

[16-03-24 06:35:44:916 PDT] 1.00000012E8

[16-03-24 06:35:44:918 PDT] 1.00000022E8

Which is correct, those are the duplicates, but I need to select every *other* row. The ones that are not duplicates.

I've tried a bunch of changes, but I just keep getting the second sheet's list repeated. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replacing `value == search` with `value != search` will not work since then it would add the row to the second sheet if even one of the rows in `saveData` is different. But it needs to check if all rows are different.

If you are sure that your volatile data sheet doesn't have any duplicates in it, you can do it this way:

```
var saveSheet = ss.getSheetByName("All Data");
loopThroughData:
for (i in data) {
  var value = data[i][3];
  for (j in saveData) {
    var search = saveData[j][3]
    if(value === search) continue loopThroughData;
    //here we leave the inner loop and jump back to the top if
    //even one row is equal
  }
  saveSheet.appendRow(data[i]);
}
```

edit: However it's usually better to use functions instead of a combination of `continue` and labels.
Therefore I would prefer this solution:

```
function updateRoster() {
  ...

  function areThereDuplicates(i) {
    var value = data[i][3];
    for(var j in saveData) {
      if(saveData[j][3] === value) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  for (i in data) {
    if(!areThereDuplicates(i)) saveSheet.appendRow(data[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great info. I'll get at is as soon as I get off work. Thanks!

Comment: That did it! A few tweaks and it's delivering as needed. Any suggestions to get it to only spit out specific columns, or should I ask that in a new question? Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well to get every OTHER value you could check for every row that is Different or "new"

```
if(value != search) {
    Logger.log(data[i][3]);
     }
```

and simply add the new rows to the file as

```
 if(value != search) {
        Logger.log(data[i][3]);
        ss.getSheetByName("All Data").appendRow(data[i]);
      }
```

Good luck =)

Comment: I tried the != version, but I feel like I have it in the wrong place because I keep getting the old data re-iterated. Thank you! I'm going to be trying all these suggestions when I get home!