# Merge filter output and remove duplicates in awesome-table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I used awesome-table to make a contact list for different services. I wanted to know if it is possible to select multiple services, merge the output and remove duplicates.

The source file/sheets contain the following columns: Service Name, name & email.

```
| Service Name | name | email |
```

Each service has its own contact information (name and email). The Service Name column is set as a CategoryFilter. So what Awesome-table does is when a service is selected, it shows the corresponding name and email as the output. It also allows multiple service names to be selected and it outputs the multiple names and emails that corresponds to the selected service names.

Currently, my template looks like this:
The Name output columns has:

```
<div class="name">{{name}}</div>
```

The Email Recipients columns has:

```
<div class="name" style="text-align: center;">{{email}}</div>
```

The template selects the data of the column with respect to the selected service name. I wanted to know how to edit the template so it can join/merge the output and remove duplicates. I.E., if I select service 1, service 2, service 3 and service 4 it would have the following output:

```
Name    Email Recipients
john doe john@domain.com
jane doe jane@domain.com
riza doe riza@domain.com
jane doe jane@domain.com
```

I wanted to have the following output:

```
Name    Email Recipients
john doe john@domain.com
jane doe jane@domain.com
riza doe riza@domain.com
```

[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DVcr.jpg)
Here is my source file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/147adG5RV1UfdKEHRPMnGCzGr8UtwBJ79Wvc5cEC4sss/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

Try using script given in the [Tutorial:Removing Duplicate Rows in a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates).

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

This script first retrieves all the data and finishes by deleting the existing content of the sheet and inserts the content of the `newData` array.

Or, you may also opt to try suggested solution given in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201974/how-do-i-merge-column-values-in-google-sheets-with-google-apps-script).