# Can't sort array passed as argument into function (TypeError, cannot call method sort of undefined)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm writing a script for sheets using Google Apps script, and I'm passing an array as an argument into a function, and I'd like to sort the array inside, and return a new array that's also been manipulated a bit after it's been sorted. I took some code from another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735677/remove-duplicates-values-in-array-google-apps-script)

The code:

```
function removeDupes(array) {
  var outArray = [];
  array.sort(); //sort incoming array according to Unicode
  outArray.push(array[0]); //first one auto goes into new array
  for(var n in array){ //for each subsequent value:
    if(outArray[outArray.length-1]!=array[n]){ //if the latest value in the new array does not equal this one we're considering, add this new one. Since the sort() method ensures all duplicates will be adjacent. V important! or else would only test if latestly added value equals it.
      outArray.push(array[n]); //add this value to the array. else, continue.
    }
  }
  return outArray;
}
```

`array.sort();` returns the error

> "TypeError: Cannot call method "sort" of undefined. (line 91, file
> "Code")"

. How can I perform the sort() method on the array passed into this function as an argument?

Comment: Can you show the usage of this function in your code? It seems likely to me that you may actually be passing it `undefined` as the argument, even if unintentionally.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Whatever code is calling `removeDupes(array)` isn't actually passing an array.

Comment: We won't know why know why you're getting that error until we can see the contents of the actual array that's being passed in.

Comment: you took `undefined` as parameter, or called the dunction without one, btw. iterating with `for ... in ` is not advisable.

Comment: Also (unrelated to issue), `for/in` loops are for looping objects with keys, not arrays. Use `.forEach()` or a standard counting loop to iterate an array.

Comment: do you need sorted unique results?

Answer (score 3):

The error is very clear, whatever code you are using to call `removeDupes` isn't passing an actual array otherwise the `.sort()` method would work on the incoming argument. [Side note: why do you need to sort the array if you are interested in removing duplicates anyway?]

Beyond that, the **[`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method can filter out duplicates without you having to do all the looping. And, even when you do loop an array, you should not use `for/in` loops, as they are for enumerating objects with string key names, not arrays. Array looping should be done with regular counting loops, `.forEach()` or one of the many customized **[`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype)** looping methods.

```js
var testArray = ["apple", "bannana", "orange", "apple", "orange"];

function removeDupes(arr){
  // The .filter method iterates all of the array items and invokes a
  // callback function on each iteration. The callback function itself
  // is automatically passed a reference to the current array item being
  // enumerated, the index of that item in the array and a reference to
  // the array being iterated. A new array is returned from filter that
  // contains whatever the callback function returns.
  return arr.filter( function( item, index, inputArray ) {
    // If the index of the item currently being enumerated is the same
    // as the index of the first occurence of the item in the array, return
    // the item. If not, don't.
    return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
  });
}

var filteredArray = removeDupes(testArray);
console.log(filteredArray);
```