# Can't find and remove duplicates in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

I've got two columns with data in them. One of the columns (on a different sheet) is a list of approved clients (approvedClients). The other is a column in the current sheet (currentClients). My goal is to look at the column in the other sheet and the column in this sheet and show the differences in the current sheet.

For example, if `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` was the current column, and the column on the other sheet was `[1,3,5,6]`, I want my result to be `[2,4]`, since 2 and 4 are the values that are present in the current column but not in the column on the other sheet.

When I run the code below, I get no error, but when I log unknownClients, I get [this](https://pastebin.com/P2XRYgHM). What's wrong?

```
function myFunction() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var cell;
 var range;

  switchSheets('Results');
  var currentClients = sheet.getRange('B2:' + sheet.getLastRow()); //gets the clients that are currently connected. 
  switchSheets('Approved clients');
  var approvedClients = sheet.getRange('A2:' + sheet.getLastRow()); //gets the clients that are approved to connect.
  switchSheets('Results');
  var unknownClients = new Array();

  for(i in currentClients){
    var row = currentClients[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in unknownClients){
      if(row == unknownClients[j]){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      unknownClients.push(row);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(unknownClients);
}
```

Comment: What is this function `switchSheets()`, can you share the code?

Comment: @JackBrown it's a custom function that changes the active sheet.

Comment: Changing active sheet doesn't retroactively change the sheet variable. It still refers to the first sheet it was assigned to.

Comment: Also, could you double check your paste bin link. It seems wrong!

Comment: Try changing `var unknownClients = new Array();` to `var unknownClients = [];`. You might also want to check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735677/remove-duplicates-values-in-array-google-apps-script) as it basically discusses the same thing.

Comment: Do you need to use a script for this? For example, `=filter(A:A, isna(match(A:A, B:B, 0)))`  shows the entries from A that are not in B.

Comment: 1 It seems that changing the sheet does retroactively change the sheet. It is a bad solution, but works. 2 I'm trying to make a 1-dimensional array, to hold only one piece of data. 3 the pastebin link was correct. 4 I want to use a script so I can chain a lot more code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my errors:
- I wasn't getting the values of the cells. I was getting a sheet object. It was logging all of the methods of the sheet object.
- I was trying to compare the list of connectedClients to the list of unknownClients, an empty array. I changed two references to unknownClients to approvedClients.
Changes I made are in caps.

I really appreciate the help from this community. I try to answer if I can, and I thank you for doing so.

```
function myFunction() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var cell;
 var range;

  switchSheets('Results');
  var currentClients = sheet.getRange('B2:' + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //ADDED THE GET VALUES
  switchSheets('Approved clients');
  var approvedClients = sheet.getRange('A2:' + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //ADDED THE GET VALUES
  switchSheets('Results');
  var unknownClients = new Array();

  for(i in currentClients){
    var row = currentClients[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in approvedClients){ //CHANGED UNKNOWN TO APPROVED
      if(row == approvedClients[j]){ //CHANGED UNKNOWN TO APPROVED
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      unknownClients.push(row);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(unknownClients);
}
```